# Initialize Empty HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I come from writing a lot of JavaScript, so bear with me.

I've got 3 HashMaps, which i reference in a method in a different class. My code (very simply) looks like so:

```
public class MainClass {
    private HashMap<String,Nation> randomHashMap = new HashMap<String,Nation>();
    DifferentClass d = new DifferentClass(this);
} //with getters/setters

public class DifferentClass {
    private MainClass mc;
    public void randomMethod() {
        System.out.println("randomHashMap is " + (mc.getRandomHashMap() == null));
    } //returns null
    public DifferentClass(MainClass c) {
        this.mc = c;
    }
}
```

However, when I call them in my other method, they're null.

How do I create a new, empty HashMap?

Comment: Make sure you initialize them in the constructor or before using them in your code.

Comment: For best understanding the problem, show your code.

Comment: The code you've provided won't even compile, unless you've *really* got a **static** method called `getRandomHashMap()` in `MainClass`.

Comment: @Luiggi but does not that code for the member variable been executed at the constructor Time?

Comment: My condolence for moving from the land of dynamic freedom to Java's type tyranny.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: The code has changed. The call to `getRandomHashMap()` was originally `MainClass.getRandomHashMap()`. (See the edit history.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your `MainClass mc` variable before using it in the `DifferentClass#randomMethod` method. Also, make sure you're using the `mc` variable instead of the `MainClass.getRandomHashMap()` method (by your actual code, we don't know how it behaves). Your code will look like this:

```
public class DifferentClass {

    private MainClass mc = new MainClass();

    public void randomMethod() {
        //assuming getRandomHashMap is the getter of randomHashMap attribute (and non static)
        System.out.println("randomHashMap is " + (mc.getRandomHashMap() == null));
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    private HashMap<String,Nation> randomHashMap = new HashMap<String,Nation>();
    DifferentClass d = new DifferentClass(this);

    public HashMap<String,Nation> getRandomHashMap() {
        return this.randomHashMap;
    }
} //with getters/setters
```

Comment: when i pass the reference in the constructor, i get errors to the stars (stack overflow errors)

Comment: @SomekidwithHTML it would depend on your design. If you want to use an instance of `MainClass` to initialize the `DifferentClass` attribute (like your code shows), it would be better to do it in the `MainClass` constructor.

Comment: I don't see how this is a solution. OP's code clearly initializes the `mc` field in its constructor, and the constructor is passed a definitely non-null value from `MainClass`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this solution does not directly solve my problem, but it made me realize what i needed to do differently, along the lines of "it would depend on your design". I realized that how I am writing this does not comply with how it needs to be designed.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is in fact perfectly all right as far as field initialization. I made an SSCCE from it with minimal intervention:

```
class Nation{}

public class MainClass {
  private HashMap<String,Nation> randomHashMap = new HashMap<String,Nation>();
  DifferentClass d = new DifferentClass(this);
  public Object getRandomHashMap() {
    return randomHashMap;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainClass().d.randomMethod();
  }
} //with getters/setters

class DifferentClass {
  private MainClass mc;
  public void randomMethod() {
      System.out.println("randomHashMap is " + (mc.getRandomHashMap() == null));
  } //returns null
  public DifferentClass(MainClass c) {
      this.mc = c;
  }
}
```

and it prints

```
randomHashMap is false
```

which proves that `randomHashMap` is indeed non-null.